# undefined is not an object react native(evaluting 'props.text')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

//******APP.js FILE********//

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput, ScrollView, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import {useState} from "react";
import GoalItem from "./components/GoalItem";
// import GoalItem from "./components/GoalItem";
export default function App() {
  const [enteredGoalText, setEnteredGoalText] = useState('')
  const [courseGoal, serCourseGoals]= useState([])
  function goalInputHandeller(enteredText){
    setEnteredGoalText(enteredText)

  }

  function  addGoalHandeller(){
    console.log(enteredGoalText)
    serCourseGoals(currentCourseGoal=>[...courseGoal,
      {text:enteredGoalText,id:Math.random().toString()},
    ])
  }
  return (
<View style={styles.appContainer}>
  <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
    <TextInput placeholder={'Enter Your Goal'} style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={goalInputHandeller}></TextInput>
    <Button title={'Add Goal'} onPress={addGoalHandeller}></Button>
  </View>
  <View  style={styles.goalsContainer}>
    <FlatList data={courseGoal} renderItem={(itemData)=>{
      return <GoalItem text={itemData.item.text}/>
      // return(
      //
      //     <View  style={styles.goalItem}>
      //       <Text style={styles.goalTExt}>{itemData.item.text}</Text></View>
      // )
    }}
              keyExtractor={(item,index)=>{
                return item.id
              }}
              alwaysBounceVertical={false}

    >



    </FlatList>
  </View>


</View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  appContainer:{
    padding: 50,
    flex:1
  },
  inputContainer:{
    flex:1,
    flexDirection:'row',
    justifyContent:'space-between',
    alignItems:'center',
    marginBottom:24,
    borderBottomWidth:1,
    borderBottomColor:'#cccccc'
  },
  textInput:{
    borderWidth:1,
    borderColor:'#CCCCCC',
    width:'70%',
    marginRight:8,
    padding:8
  },
  goalsContainer:{
    flex:4
  },
  goalItem:{
    margin:8,
    padding:8,
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor:'#5e0acc',
    color:'white'
  },
  goalTExt:{
    color:'white'
  }

});
```

GoalInput.js FILE

```
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from "react-native";

function GoalItem(props){
    return(
        <View  style={styles.goalItem}>
            <Text style={styles.goalTExt}>
                {props.text}
            </Text>
        </View>
        )

}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    goalItem:{
        margin:8,
        padding:8,
        borderRadius: 6,
        backgroundColor:'#5e0acc',
        color:'white'
    },
    goalText:{
        color:'white'
    }
})
export default GoalItem();
```

ERROR
12:19
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.text')

Stack trace:
node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:95:4 in reportException
node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
node_modules@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:203:6 in guardedLoadModule
http://192.168.1.7:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:120749:3 in global code
...
ERROR
12:19
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

Stack trace:
node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:95:4 in reportException
node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
node_modules@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:370:8 in __guard
node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:113:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
[native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
...
This is what I get when I run it with expo
[This is ss or error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLE3F.jpg)

Comment: I don't know that much react, but shouldn't you use `export default GoalItem;` rather than `export default GoalItem();` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN your flatlist try this, add curly braces to renderItem

```
<FlatList data={courseGoal} renderItem={({data})=>{
      return <GoalItem text={data?.item?.text}/>
     
    }} />
```

also for null safety try this in goalFile

```
function GoalItem(props){
    return(
        <View  style={styles.goalItem}>
            <Text style={styles.goalTExt}>
                {props?.text ?? ""}
            </Text>
        </View>
        )

}
```

and also export should be as Cid said `export default GoalItem`